# Improve image quality of "Decoration"

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, legend, image, pixel

I imported a key using Decorations -> Image in QGIS 3.32 and the quality is poor, especially if the image is made smaller. I do not mean that the actual image file is small, but that displaying the image as a smaller size in QGIS makes it more compressed and pixelated.
Here is the same image at 56 vs 26 mm
[image]

The larger one is legible; however, it is still very pixelated and of lower quality than if I open the project in 3.22.5, where this image quality issue does not exist.
[image]

I need to use a plug-in which only works in 3.32. Is there an image setting causing this problem? PNG versus JPEG has no effect.